# cp command asking for confirmation of overwrite even with -f switch (zsh)

Tags: zsh, cp

I have the following in a file which is sourced from `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Starship prompt
cp -f ~/.config/starship.toml ~/.config/starship-zsh.toml
export STARSHIP_CONFIG="$HOME/.config/starship-zsh.toml"
starship config character.success_symbol "[%](white)"
starship config character.error_symbol "[%](bold red)"
eval "$(starship init zsh)"
```

This is so that I only need to keep one starship configuration file updated for both bash and zsh, but still have a different prompt character for each.

When logging in I get asked whether it is okay to overwrite the existing file. This doesn't happen with I put the above lines in `.zshrc` itself, but it does in this file that is sourced from `.zshrc`. I have it like this as this file is conditionally sourced only when a certain set of packages have been installed.

I can workaround this by deleting the file first, but I would like to know why this is happening even with the `-f` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an alias or wrapper function that sets some option which overrides the effect of `-f`. Use `\command cp` to force the use of the command directly, bypassing functions and aliases.

(The leading `\` is for the unlikely case where you have something like `alias command='command '` set.)

Comment: Oh, of course, I forgot that these files are being sourced in the current shell so my aliases would affect anything in them.

Comment: It's a bit annoying and confusing that `-f` doesn't cancel `-i` in `cp` (as the OP likely has a `cp() command cp -i "$@"` function or `alias cp='cp -i` alias) like it does for `rm` and `mv`, but it has different semantics in `cp`; it's about removing the destination file if any before creating the copy anew instead of overwriting it so is not the opposite of `-i` there.

Comment: In general, aliasing `cp` or `rm` to include the `-i` option is a really bad idea. Sooner or later you'll find yourself on a system without your settings and wonder why `rm *` has just finished very quickly instead of prompting you. Give the aliases a different name.